# How to execute time consuming procedure asynchronously in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I need to execute a certain Oracle procedure from the client application and it usually takes longer time and can not really increase the waiting time for the response as the execution time is unpredictable!

Is there a way to execute the the procedure as a scheduler job asynchronously at run time?

If asynchronously executed would "Oracle AQ Asynchronous Notification" be used to notify back the application?

Comment: Try `DBMS_JOB` or `dbms_scheduler` refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dbms_scheduler` package (or the older `dbms_job` package) to run a procedure in a separate session asynchronously.  Depending on the number of jobs you envision running (and the number of background jobs you want your application to write to some sort of job queue that a fixed number of background jobs read from to pick up and process work.  That "job queue" could be an actual Oracle AQ queue or it could be a regular table that the jobs read from.

You could have the procedure send a message to the client using Oracle AQ as well.  99% of the time that I've seen this sort of setup, however, the job wrote some sort of status to a table (or just used the `dbms_scheduler` data dictionary) and the front-end merely polled the status periodically to determine when the job was done.